# SQL Add a filtering parameter without altering the data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL command to get a Project Number, a Project Title, an Employee name & number from a database.

```
SELECT
DOS.NUMFOLDER as ProjectNumber, 
DOS.DESCRIPTION as ProjectTitle, 
EMP.NUMEMPL as EmployeeNumber, 
EMP.EMPLNAME+ ' ' + EMP.EMPLSURNAME as EmployeeName

FROM DOSEMPDT               DEM 
INNER JOIN DOSSIER          DOS ON DEM.SEQCONTRAT = DOS.SEQCONTRAT 
INNER JOIN EMPLOYE          EMP ON DEM.SEQEMPLOYE = EMP.SEQEMPLOYE 
--INNER JOIN BILLING        BIL ON DEM.SEQCONTRAT = FAC.SEQCONTRAT 

WHERE (DEM.DATEFINAFF IS NULL OR DEM.DATEFINAFF > GETDATE()) 
AND (DOS.DATEFIN IS NULL OR DOS.DATEFIN > GETDATE())
--AND FAC.DTBILLING IS NOT NULL
--AND FAC.DTBILLING >= DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE())

ORDER BY NoProjet
```

This gives me what I want; A table with the project number, project title, and an employee. The intended result looks a bit like this:

```
projectA   *titlea*   1111   Jim
projectA   *titlea*   2222   James
projectB   *titleb*   1111   Jim
projectB   *titleb*   3333   Paul
```

But I want to add a filter to the results. I still want to see multiple instances of the same project, with the associated employee, but I want to see only certain projects; those with a `BILLING` date of less than a month ago, without displaying said `BILLING`.

Removing the comment before the `INNER JOIN BILLING`, makes the results duplicated many times, probably because many projects have many `BILLING` but I'm not sure how to avoid that. I think the problem resides in my 3rd `INNER JOIN`, and I've tried `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`, etc... but to no avail.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Your syntax is SQL Server so I removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: I assumed I was doing this incorrectly, but actually the problem was that I wasn't expecting the data to be like they are (2 different invoices for the same date, same employee and same project), So I assumed I was creating duplicate entries. Thanks @Mohamed Seifeddine Fnayou for putting me on the right track. I will vote close the question as it doesn't make much sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are just showing the duplicate data.

As a matter of fact, the invoices table would have the contract sequence number along with the relative invoices IDs. For instance

```
Project A   Invoice_001 
Project A   Invoice_002
```

With your current SELECT, you'll get always :

```
projectA   *titlea*   1111   Jim  
projectA   *titlea*   2222   James  
projectB   *titleb*   1111   Jim  
projectB   *titleb*   3333   Paul
```

But, if you add the invoices Column in your SELECT, you'll probably get :

```
projectA   *titlea*   1111   Jim   Invoice_001  
projectA   *titlea*   1111   Jim   Invoice_002  
projectA   *titlea*   2222   James Invoice_003  
projectB   *titleb*   1111   Jim   Invoice_004  
projectB   *titleb*   3333   Paul  Invoice_005
```

So, no more duplicate data !

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with `exists`:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM DOSEMPDT DEM INNER JOIN
     DOSSIER DOS
     ON DEM.SEQCONTRAT = DOS.SEQCONTRAT INNER JOIN
     EMPLOYE EMP
     ON DEM.SEQEMPLOYE = EMP.SEQEMPLOYE 
WHERE (DEM.DATEFINAFF IS NULL OR DEM.DATEFINAFF > GETDATE())  AND
      (DOS.DATEFIN IS NULL OR DOS.DATEFIN > GETDATE()) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM FACTURE FAC
              WHERE DEM.SEQCONTRAT = FAC.SEQCONTRAT AND
                    FAC.DTFACTURE IS NOT NULL AND
                    FAC.DTFACTURE >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
             )
```

Comment: I tried this, and am only getting each project once, when before I had it several times with different employees associated with it. Is this intended? If so, it is not exactly what I want... I'll try to edit my question and make it clearer.